# Downgrade mysql version 5.6.20 to 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, downgrade

I want to downgrade mysql  5.6.20 to 5.1, can anyone give me steps using phpmyadmin...or any other better way to downgrade it. I'm using windows 7 and xampp server. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: PHP 5.1 was obsolete in 2008.

PHPMyAdmin is used to access databases and it can't be used to install or modify the installed PHP.

Comment: @ryantxr The question was about MySQL, not PHP. MySQL 5.1 went into "sustaining support" (basically EOL) in December 2013, though, so it's still a poor choice to downgrade to…

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to take a dump of all your DB. Uninstall 5.6.20. Install 5.1 and restore your data.